# validating a newly added registration form filed in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I have added a new field for the registration form called ID Number and i want validate it as a required filed. I have added the below codes

catalog\language\english\account\register.php

catalog\language\english\checkout\checkout.php

```
$_['antry_nicd']          = 'ID Number:';
$_['error_nicd']          = 'Please enter a valid ID Number!';
```

and in the controller

catalog\controller\checkout\register.php

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['nicd']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['nicd']) > 11)) {
                    $json['error']['nicd'] = $this->language->get('error_nicd');
                }
```

catalog\controller\checkout\guest.php

```
if (isset($this->session->data['guest']['nicd'])) {
    $this->data['nicd'] = $this->session->data['guest']['nicd'];
} else {
    $this->data['nicd'] = '';
}
```

in my form it shows the text field but it doest validate or show the error, All the other required fields show the error.

can someone please tell me how can i make it show the error and what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

you will need to add some code to your template files...

Open catalog/view/theme/*/template/checkout/register.tpl and find the following:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="" class="large-field" />
```

and then after it add:

```
  <br />
  <br />
  <span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_ncid; ?><br />
  <input type="text" name="ncid" value="" class="large-field" />
```

and then open catalog/view/theme/*/template/checkout/checkout.tpl and find the following:

```
if (json['error']['email']) {
```

You will find that there are three occurrences... two are for payment details and one is for shipping details (the line below "if (json['error']['email']) {" shows if it is a shipping address or a payment address), depending on your configuration will depend on whether you do all three...

and before it add:

```
if (json['error']['ncid']) {
                $('#payment-address input[name=\'ncid\'] + br').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['ncid'] + '</span>');
            }
```

You will then need to do the same thing to the register template file...

Open catalog/view/theme/*/template/account/register.tpl  find the following:

```
<td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
```

and then after it add (offset it by 4):

```
    <tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_ncid; ?></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ncid" value="<?php echo $ncid; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_ncid) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_ncid; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
```

Please vote my answer up if it helped...

That should solve it... let me know if you have any problems...

many thanks
Jeremy

Comment: thanks alot. i made the changes to the checkout.tpl and it worked. But i cant find `json['error']['email']` in the register.tpl. Any help on this please?

Comment: Sorry, what version of opencart are you using... and i will tell you exactly what to do if you can tell me that...

Comment: the version is OC 1.5.6

Comment: Sorry, i added that part by mistake... in the register.tpl don't worry about it

Comment: try that and see how it goes... If that answered it, please tick that it did (and please rate my comments)...